# Beamer --- Replace one word with another

Tags: beamer

I would like to replace one word with another in a paragraph in my Beamer presentation.

Example:

First Slide
Roses are red

Second Slide
Flowers are red

i.e. when I click, Roses should be replaced by Flowers

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: is your intent that "are red" not move during the substitution?  this should be possible (although some finagling of the spacing is required) when the substitution is at the beginning or end of the string, but it's a lot harder in the middle, especially if the two alternating words aren't the same length.

Answer (score 33):

There are several options:

You can use `\only`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\only<1>{Roses}\only<2>{Flowers} are red.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can use `\alt`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\alt<2>{Flowers}{Roses} are red.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]